When a selection is made and a specific cell is empty, it brings up a notification so the user pays attention in Google Sheets
If a selection is made from range D1:D9 I want cell A1 to blink if it's empty & if a selection is made from range D10:D18 cell A10 to blink if it's empty. How should I adjust the formula that I am using?
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(["D1:D8", "D10:D18"]); 
  var originalColor = range.getBackground(); //It gets the original color
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (range.getValue() === "") {
      rangeList.setBackground("red");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      range.setBackground(originalColor); //It keeps the original color
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
}

The sample file is Flash Cell Test
The whole point of blinking is for the user to pay attention to a specific cell/s.
When he makes the selection in column D (from two different ranges), pay attention and do not forget to put a value to the specific cells A1 & A10 respectively.

Your code accesses the sheet multiple times, which reduces performance. Why would you use a toast to get the user's attention instead of blinking?
Try this code:
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var ss = e.source;
  var range = e.range;
  var a1 = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var a10 = sh.getRange('A10').getValue();

  if (range.getColumn() !== 4) return;
  if (a1 !== '' && a10 !== '') return;

  ss.toast('First fill out cells A1 and A10.', 'Attention', 3);
}


Boris thank you for your reply. It could be a solution since I could change the toast display time and with the right message to get their attention. I also tested it with multiple TABS in the same sheet and it works!
I have two questions:
Is it possible to change the position to be on the top left for example or is it always on the down right side corner?
Can you change the color?

Alas, the toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds) method only has 3 parameters.

Do I have to change the tile because your solution is different from what I am asking?

Your goal was not to blink, but to draw the user's attention. However, when you asked the question, you did not assume that in addition to blinking there is also toast(). I'm not sure if the title needs to be changed.

I edited the title so someone who's seeking the same solution finds it easier when searching. Thank you Boris once more!
